# Conduit simple file read expression not typechecking

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm trying to get a simple [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) example under my belt, but I'm failing at the type-checking phase. In [this example](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/resourcet#resourcet-is-not-conduit), I'm seeing `ResourceT` being used as the conduit "executor", if that makes sense. I also know that, for some time, `ResourceT` has been [factored-out into it's own package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet). However, I still can't get a simple example working. Here is my code, which was inspired by [this article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview#basics):

```
import qualified Data.Conduit as C
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString (..))
import System.IO

printFile file = runResourceT $ CB.sourceFile file C.$$ print'
  where
    print' :: C.Sink ByteString IO ()
    print' = CL.mapM_ $ putStrLn · unpack
```

And here is the error I'm getting (my package is called "conduit-playground":

```
Preprocessing library conduit-playground-0.0.0...
[2 of 2] Compiling Playground       ( src/Playground.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-13da96d6/build/Playground.o )

src/Playground.hs:12:57:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO’
                  with ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT m’
    Expected type: C.Sink
                     ByteString (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT m) ()
      Actual type: C.Sink ByteString IO ()
    Relevant bindings include
      printFile :: FilePath -> m () (bound at src/Playground.hs:12:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(C.$$)’, namely ‘print'’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘CB.sourceFile file C.$$ print'’
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
conduit-playground-0.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

If I leave out `runResourceT`, I'm still getting a typeclass error for there not being an instance of `MonadResource` for `IO`. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ResourceT, but it appears you're trying to force a type of print' that doesn't match the transformer stack. What happens if you remove the explicit signature?

Comment: It assumes `print'` to be a `Conduit` instead of a `Sink`, causing even more type errors :/

Comment: I think, really, this comes down to not having an instance of `MonadResource` for `IO`. For instance, `CL.mapM_ putStrLn :: MonadResource m => Sink String m ()` doesn't work; there's no instance (probably for a good reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `print'` has an incompatible type

```
print' :: C.Sink ByteString IO ()
```

You can't have `IO` as the base monad of a conduit if you are using `ResourceT` (which you need in this case for reading the file). The simplest monad that lets you both print and handle file resources is `ResourceT IO` i.e. the `IO` monad transformed with the `ResourceT` transformer.

```
print' :: C.Sink ByteString (ResourceT IO) ()
print' = CL.mapM_ $ liftIO . putStrLn · unpack
```

The `liftIO` is needed to "lift" the expression of type `IO ()` into `ResourceT IO ()`. You could also use the more generic signature

```
print' :: MonadIO m => C.Sink ByteString m ()
```

to make a utility function that works with any conduit that is able to perform IO.

`MonadIO` and `liftIO` can be imported from the module `Control.Monad.IO.Class`.